# Regular Expression to match all non-word character unless between numbers

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Trying to develop a regex in Java 8 flavor to match all non-word characters in several different strings, so I can split them. The only exception is when the ":" is between numbers, such as in "8:00AM".

So far, I've come up with this: `"\W(?:(?<!\d)(?!\d))|[-/](?=\d)"`

Given the strings below, I got the following result:

> M-F: 10AM - 6PM
>
> M-D: 9am / 6pm F: 9am / 4pm
>
> Seg-Qui: 08h às 17h Sex: 08h às 16h
>
> L-V: 8:00AM - 6:00PM CST
>
> M, F, 10AM-5PM
>
> Lun-Jeu: 9/18h Ven:9/17h

[image: regex matches]

However, there are the following issues:

In the string *Lun-Jeu: 9/18h Ven:9/17h*, it's not selecting the ":" in *Ven:9*.

In the string *Seg-Qui: 08h às 17h Sex: 08h às 16h*, I also would like to select the whole word "às" if possible.

Could anyone help to fix the regex or provide a better solution to achieve this?

Comment: Looking at `[-/]` in your regex, you did not specify any requirements regarding the `-` or `/` chars followed with digits. Are you sure you explained the problem as you need? Note `(?<!\d)(?!\d)` is not going to work as you expect because lookarounds do not move regex index when matching, this means no digit immediately on the left and right at this very location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(?U)\W(?<!\d:(?=\d))
```

In Java:

```java
String regex = "(?U)\\W(?<!\\d:(?=\\d))";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xe2hoJ/2).

*Details*:

- `(?U)` - `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded flag option, makes `\d` and `\W` and other shorthands Unicode-aware
- `\W` - any word char
- `(?<!\d:(?=\d))` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately precedd with  a digit and `:`, and immediately followed with a digit.

To also fail the match of a dot inside digits, use `(?U)\W(?<!\d[:.](?=\d))`. You may add more chars there if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)[^\p{L}\d]|[^\p{L}\d](?!\d)
```

It selects anything not a unicode letter (ie which includes `à`) or digit, but only if either not preceded by a digit, or not followed by a digit.

Comment: this one didn't work for me because it doesn't match the "/" in Ven:9/17h